# Do touch.rotationAngle and touch.radiusY work on mobile (iOS)?

Tags: javascript, touch

I am using the example provided by MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/radiusX#example) but touch.rotationAngle is always 0 and touch.radiusY alway equals touch.radiusX.

MDN says "This attribute is not widely implemented", but knowing for sure would be helpful.

So do touch.rotationAngle and touch.radiusY work on mobile (iOS/firefox and iOS/Chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

In the [browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/radiusX#browser_compatibility), iOS/Firefox and iOS/Chrome are not listed as supported platforms. Therefore, it looks like these browsers on iOS don't support the attribute.